Does the estimate of a nonparametric function changes when adding a parametric component?
I am estimating a semiparametric and a non-parametric model using a GAM function with the package mcgv in R. In particular I am estimating the two following models:
y = s(x) 
y = s(x) + Z'b

where x enters the model non parametrically, while Z is a vector of additional variables that enter the model in a linear way, for which I estimate the coefficients b.
My main interest is to obtain and plot the nonlinear relationship between y and x, I add the additional variables zjust for consistency with the rest of the analysis.  I do that for different subsamples (based on quartiles of a third variable k) and then I plot the resulting curves.
My question is the following: does the estimated s(x) function change when moving from a parametric to a semiparametric setting?
As far as I understand, it should not change, as the semiparametric model is either first estimating s(x), than obtaining y' = y - s(x) and then running the parametric estimation y' = Z'b + error, or the other way around, starting from the parametric component. Source is here, chapter 7.1.
Visually, what should happen is that I should need to add the Z'b component to get the same curve, otherwise the curve will be shifted downards or upwards as s(x) would be only showing a partial effect.
Am I correct?
Here is a reproducible R code
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)  ##for gam()

set.seed(123)
y <- rnorm(1000)
x <- rnorm(1000)
z1 <- rnorm(1000)
z2 <- rnorm(1000)
data <- data.frame(y = y, x = x, z1 = z1, z2 = z2)

# nonparametric
gam_npar <- gam(y~ s(x), data = data)
plot(gam_npar )
# or
plot.gam(gam_npar )


# semi-parametric
gam_sp <- gam(y~ s(x) + z1 + z2, data = data)
plot(gam_sp )
# or
plot.gam(gam_sp)

You can plot the non parametric outcome directly in ggplot2 too, but I cannot seem to make it work for the semiparametric version
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(shape = 3) +  # Add scatter plot of data_filter points
 geom_smooth(aes(method = "gam", se = FALSE)) +  
  labs(title = "non par") +
    theme_minimal()

I attach two plots using my actual data, first one is without additional variables, the second one is with a set of additional variables entering the model parametrically. Differences are minimal and I am not sure why.


If I follow a different approach for plotting, differences disappear, as for instance:
gam_model <- gam(y ~ s(x) + z1 + z2, data = data)
# Define the range for the predictor x
x_range <- seq(min(data$x), max(data$x), length.out = 100)

predictions <- predict(gam_model, newdata = newdata, se.fit = TRUE)

plot(x_range, predictions$fit, type = "l", col = "blue", lwd = 2,
     xlab = "x", ylab = "Predicted y",
     main = "GAM Predictions with Confidence Intervals")
lines(x_range, predictions$fit + 2 * predictions$se.fit, col = "red", lty = 2)
lines(x_range, predictions$fit - 2 * predictions$se.fit, col = "red", lty = 2)

